# Cómo convertir un const char a un char en C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Estoy luchando con un trabajo de la facultad donde en una parte me piden pasar de un const char a una cadena de char... Estoy buscando documentación y no encuentro nada que me pueda servir, si conoces alguna librería o alguna función te estaría eternamente agradecido si me la comentas
este esta es la funcion que me esta complicando

```
struct rep_evento {
  int id;
  TFecha dia;
  char descripcion;
}

TEvento crearEvento(int id,
  const char descripcion[MAX_DESCRIPSION], TFecha fecha) {
  TEvento nuevoEvento = new rep_evento;
  char descrip;
  strcpy(descripcion[MAX_DESCRIPCION]); // no
  me funciono nuevoEvento -> id = id;
  nuevoEvento -> dia = fecha;
  nuevoEvento -> descripcion = descrip; // me
  marca error aqui
  return nuevoEvento;
}
```

Comment: En C o C++ puedes usar una conversión explícita, agregando `(char*)` antes de la variable. En realidad no deberías forzar está conversión ya que podrías estar leyendo memoria de solo lectura y obtendrás un error si intentas escribir en ella.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]? Ambos son lenguajes **diferentes** y la respuesta será muy diferente dependiendo del lenguaje que realmente quieras usar.

Comment: Debes observar las definiciones del dato ```descripcion```. En tu estructura ```descripción``` es un ```char``` es decir, sólo podrás poner un carácter. Por otro lado, la variable ```descripción``` del método ```crearEvento``` es un arreglo de caracteres, ```descripción[MAX-DESCRIPCION]]```. Este último es totalmente diferente a ```descripción``` a la de tu estructura porque este es solo un ```char```, por lo tanto, no puedes tratarlos por igual, aunque en ```c``` podrías hacerlo mediante punteros pero te traes un error fatal. Corrige tu código. Aparte que es strcpy(descripcion)  falat un dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- La asignación no es correcta.

  En el struct tienes un solo carácter mientras que `descripcion` es un arreglo de caracteres.
- No puedes recibir un arreglo como parámetro. Si lo haces, el parámetro se convierte en puntero.
- Aquí no estás pasando tu arreglo, estás accediendo a una posición potencialmente inválida:

  ```
  strcpy(descripcion[MAX_DESCRIPCION]);
  ```

  Además la función [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) toma 2 parámetros, el primer byte de la región de memoria a la que se va copiar (destino) y el primer byte de la región que se va a copiar (origen).

---

Necesitas que `descripcion` del struct sea un puntero o un arreglo.

Así, si es un puntero, le puedes asignar otro puntero.

```
struct rep_evento {
    int id;
    TFecha dia;
    char* descripcion;
}

TEvento crearEvento(int id, const char * descripcion, TFecha fecha) {
    TEvento nuevoEvento = new rep_evento;
    nuevoEvento->descripcion = descripcion;
    ...
}
```

O si es un arreglo, puedes copiar con [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) su contenido.

```
struct rep_evento {
    int id;
    TFecha dia;
    char descripcion[MAX_DESCRIPCION];
}

TEvento crearEvento(int id, const char *descripcion, TFecha fecha) {
    TEvento nuevoEvento = new rep_evento;
    
strcpy(nuevoEvento->descripcion, descripcion);
    ...
}
```

---

Si estás en C++, una mejor alternativa es la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) que puedes usar de esta manera:

```
struct rep_evento {
    int id;
    TFecha dia;
    std::string descripcion;
}

TEvento crearEvento(int id, const std::string &descripcion, TFecha fecha) {
    TEvento nuevoEvento = new rep_evento;
    nuevoEvento->descripcion = descripcion;
    ...
}
```

La referencia es para que no se cree una copia innecesaria del string.